# Rails Minitest with relations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am trying to create a test that checks if answers can be created. Answers can only exist under questions. Here is the code for my test:

```
test "should be able to create answer" do
    answer = answers(:answer1)
    assert_difference("Answer.count") do
        post :create, answer: {body: answer.body, question: answer.question}
    end
    assert_equal "Je vraag is ingedient!", flash[:notice], "Incorrect flash notice"
end
```

asd

In the controller there is a redirect to the parent question of the answer:

```
redirect_to @answer.question
```

But it redirects to nil because no question is created thus no parent:

```
ActionControllerError: Cannot redirect to nil!
```

How do i write a test for this situation???

fixtures:
answers.yml

```
answer1:
  body: Practice in in front of your parents
  question: question1
```

questions.yml

```
question1:
  title: What is the best way to prepare a presentations in another      language?
  body: I have to pitch in my class.
```

Comment: Could you add both code of your `create` action and your `Answer` model?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the question before creating the answer like this:

```
test "should be able to create question" do
    question = questions(:question1)
    assert_difference("Question.count") do
        post :create, question: {title: question.title, body: question.body}
    end
    assert_redirected_to question_path(assigns(:question)), "Not redirected to question"
    assert_equal "Je vraag is ingedient!", flash[:notice], "Incorrect flash notice"
end
```